# Will the disguise created during Masquerade work for Viper's Nest?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

Title pretty much says it.

Am on my third playthrough. Previous two times I've stealthed my way around inside the camp, and from what I've been reading - putting on a Cuman set of armor gives dubious results.

So I'm wondering, will the disguise set created during Masquerade work here?  Am playing Hardcore so it's a bit of a trek to complete that quest. Would be good to know if it's worth the effort at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using that disguise to infiltrate Cuman camps (and the big camp for the Viper's nest).   They don't immediately attack, but they follow you and talk to you in their Cuman language (they sound suspicious), and attack you in a minute or so.   It might buy you some time to leave if you do get spotted, but you can't just freely walk around their camps.

Comment: Right ok. Sounds pretty much like the results I've been reading about, using a looted set of armor. Makes sense I suppose, the Masquerade disguise has a bit more "bling" on it ;-)